# How to return just number from id like "post-46"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried looking for solutions and found some that used regular expressions for this, but didn't work for me, but basically how can I (using jQuery) get just the number bit from id like `#post-46`

This is how I get id at the moment:

```
nowPlaying = $("article.playing").attr("id");
```

which returns something like `post-2`, `post-9192` etc.. How can I modify it to simply return the number? Possibly without regular expressions?

Comment: `nowPlaying = $("article.playing").attr("id").split("-")` then target `nowPlaying[1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var nowPlaying = $("article.playing").prop("id").split('-')[1];
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
var idNum = nowPlaying.split('-').pop();
console.log(idNum);
```

Split your `id` first and then `pop` which will get you the last item in the array which contains the number

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
nowPlaying = $("article.playing").attr("id").replace("post-", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do your job without calling REGEX.

```
nowPlaying = $("article.playing").attr("id").replace("post-", "");
```

Shortest and simplest answer